# how to complete date fields with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the data for two dates as start and end. It should be like this:
if the start month is 01, The end month must be 12 and end years must be the start year.
if the start month is not 01, The end month must be start month - 1 and end years must be the start year + 1.
for example:
start date: 2012/01 -----> end date: 2012/12
start date: 2012/02-----> end date: 2013/01

I tried this code:

```
<script defer>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datatable_years").DataTable();
        $("#start_month_year").on('change',function (){
            var year = $(this).val().trim()
            var month = $("#start_month_month").val().trim()
            if (year.length == 4){
                if (!isNaN(year)){
                    $("#end_month_year").val(function(){
                        if(month== 0o1){
                            $("#end_month_year").val(parseInt(year))
                        }else{
                            $("#end_month_year").val(parseInt(year)+1)
                        } 
                    })
                }
            }
        })
        $("#start_month_month").on('change',function (){
            var month = $(this).val().trim()
            if (month.length == 2){
                if (!isNaN(month)){
                    if(month== 01){
                        $("#end_month_month").val(12)
                        $("#end_month_year").val(parseInt(year))
                    }else{
                        $("#end_month_month").val(month)
                        $("#end_month_year").val(parseInt(year)+1)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

but the year does not complete right.

Comment: Move your check/update code to its own stand-alone function.  Have both event handlers call that function (without `this` - doesn't matter if it's the month or year that changes).